# how to get list of all dedicated server in Api Soyoustart?

Tags: dedicated-server

I want to get list of all available dedicated server from api soyoustart.Any clue?
In ovh api we can get the list by /order/catalog/formatted/{catalogName} but I can't find any similar command. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the API url to get all SoYouStart (and others servers) available as JSON :

> https://www.ovh.com/engine/api/dedicated/server/availabilities?country=en

I suggest to use this website to analyze the returned JSON : http://jsoneditoronline.org/

**Returned object explanation**

Here is one of the 3303 items returned (each item represent a hardware, or a discount):

```
{
    "hardware": "1804armada01",
    "region": "europe",
    "datacenters": [
      {
        "availability": "unavailable",
        "datacenter": "default"
      },
      {
        "datacenter": "gra",
        "availability": "unavailable"
      },
      {
        "datacenter": "sbg",
        "availability": "unavailable"
      },
      {
        "datacenter": "rbx",
        "availability": "unavailable"
      },
      {
        "availability": "unavailable",
        "datacenter": "waw"
      },
      {
        "availability": "unavailable",
        "datacenter": "fra"
      },
      {
        "availability": "unavailable",
        "datacenter": "lon"
      }
    ]
},
```

For each datacenter you have the availability.

> The hardware "1804armada01" is the SoYouStart ARM-2T (CANADA). You can find hardware id inspecting the order page of so you start at >https://www.soyoustart.com/fr/serveurs-stockage/:
>
> data-ref="1801armada01"

---

NB: If you just want to use the API to know when a server is available, free services exist like https://kimsufi-notifier.com/